# Measure the performance of spring batch StaxEventItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

We have spring batch job which parse xmls file and we want to log how long it is taking to parse xml against schema. Is there anyway where we can measure this performance?

In past we have used job execution and step execution listener

Comment: What prevents you from using your old solution?

Comment: When you use steplistener, you are measuring performance of reader,processor and writer. We need to measure performance of only reader